# I used 'LIKE' on searching after 2 dept for the same column But no result...!

Tags: sql-like

```
SELECT *
FROM JOBS_table
```

my like such following;

1. `WHERE Job_id (1st) LIKE 'IT%'`
2. `AND Job_id (2nd) LIKE 'SA%';`

Comment: can anyone help me on this please ?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting a field, which is starting with IT AND starting with SA, which will never be satisfyable.

Either you use "OR" or if you search in a string with "LIKE %IT%" AND "%SA%".

Comment: for further analysis, it would be good, to have a description and example of fiel Job_id